# React SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

```
    import React from 'react';


    class FetchData extends React.Component{
        state = {}

      setStateAsync(state) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          this.setState(state, resolve)
        });
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
        const url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow"
        const res = await fetch(url,{mode:'no-cors'})
        const data = await res.json()
        await this.setStateAsync({data:data})
      }

        render(){
            return (
              <div>
               {this.state.data}
              </div>
            );
        }
    }

export default FetchData
```

i am trying to make a simple wikipedia viewer app. I checked the network and tried using simple fetch function but this error seems to persist.

Comment: Did you validate your query in a tool such as Postman? Are you getting the raw data you are expecting?

Comment: It works in postman.

Comment: Yes, I tested it myself, thanks. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Setting mode to 'no-cors' in your fetch does not resolve CORS issues, it merely ignores them.
According to the Wikipedia API docs, you can add an '&origin=*' to your request to make an unauthenticated CORS request ([see here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests)).

Finally, you will want to initiate your state with an empty 'data' object, and you'll have to stringify the object in your render method (you can't have objects as children in a React render method).

[See here for a working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4rx9yqzyz).